# Oracle SQL PLS-00049: bad bind variable ERROR

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm doing a trigger that when inserting a shirt number verifies if it already exists in the database, I also did a function called 'VERIFYSHIRT' that the trigger calls. When compiling i've received an Oracle SQL PLS-00049: bad bind variable ERROR. I'm almost sure that the code is right, but don't know what i'm doing wrong. If you guys want I can also put the function here, thanks in advance, or any table needed!

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SHIRT_NUMBER 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Player
    FOR EACH ROW

      DECLARE
      shirtNumber NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      shirtNumber := VERIFYSHIRT(:NEW.CLUB_CLUBID,:NEW.PLAYER_SHIRTNUMBER);

      if  shirtNumber > 0 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Shirt number already exists!');
      NULL;
     END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a trigger? What should the trigger do? Please post an example of what kind of data the trigger should avoid to create

Comment: If you create a unique index on the column that stores the `shirtNumber` data, wouldn't that accomplish the same thing, and eliminate the need for both the `SHIRT_NUMBER` trigger and the `VERIFYSHIRT` function?

Answer (score 0):

A `trigger that when inserting a shirt number verifies if it already exists in the database` shouldn't be created.

This is what a primary key is for, use it!

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/primary_keys.php